# Does ADO wrappers for SQLLite preserve performance?

Tags: sqlite

Does ADO wrappers to SQLLite assume significant interprocess communications (as for example SQL Server does as far as it is separate process)? As far as I know SQL Lite is DLL loaded inproc (it's fast - no need in IPC overhead), so, does using ADO wrapper preserve this benefit? (for example this -  [System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki))

Comment: How would such an assumption make any difference? When you give an SQL command to ADO, it *must* execute it immediately; what else could it do?

Comment: Ok. Does ADO wrappers to SQLLite assume ANY interprocess communications?